# Showing two stochastic process are independent

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, independence

Let $X=\{X_t, t \ge 0\}$ and  $Y=\{Y_t, t \ge 0\}$ are two stochastic processes defined on common probability space. Then two show X and Y are independent, does it suffice to show for any $t$ and $s$, $X_t$ and $Y_s$ are independent? Or do we need stronger conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that the sigma-algebras $\sigma(\{X_t \mid t \ge 0\})$ and $\sigma(\{Y_t \mid t \ge 0\})$ are independent, it isn't sufficient that all pairs $X_t, Y_t$ are independent.

This can easily be seen by the following example: Let $X, Y$ be two independent random variables with nontrivial distribution. Then the processes
$$\begin{align*}X_t &= X \cdot I\{t = 0\} + Y \cdot I\{t = 1\} \\
Y_t &= X \cdot I\{t = 1\} + Y \cdot I\{t = 0\}\end{align*}$$
are not independent, although all pairs $X_t, Y_t$ are independent.

---

**Edit:** The question was changed since I've answered it. To answer the new question, consider the [standard example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1387901/259493) of random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ that are pairwise independent, but not jointly independent. Now consider the processes
$$\begin{align*}Y_t &= X_1 \cdot I\{t = 0\} + X_2 \cdot I\{t = 1\} \\
Z_t &= X_3 \cdot I\{t = 0\}\end{align*}.$$

Comment: How about any $t$ and $s$ though? In above case $X_1$ and $Y_0$ are not independent for example.

Comment: You can still easily produce counterexamples. Simply look up a typical example of three random variables that are pairwise independent, but not jointly independent.